# Generate Entities of database using doctrine with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

How can I generate Entities for Database using Doctrine and Codeigniter?

I found this line

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml
```

But I did not know where I have to write it or how can I open the console of doctrine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code line runs in terminal, go to your project directory and run this command finally create entity file but just create database mapping not complete entity.

Use examples below,

## Create entity mapping

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --filter="FollowedLink" ApiBundle annotation
```

## Create Entity

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities ApiBundle/Entity/FollowedLink
```

Comment: thank you.
I link the terminal with php.exe
and using your lines, but I get this error 
`C:\Users\Mahfouz>php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle XML
Could not open input file: bin/console

C:\Users\Mahfouz>`

Comment: This command for symfony 3 framework, doctrine document page for about this topic [Doctrine Console](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html)

Comment: How i can do it for Codeigniter